# Range Validation in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

"  I m making a web application on visual studio and i want to use c# codes mostly so please if any one can tell me how to make both "mandatory field" as well as" specific range" validation on the click of submit button using C# coding in asp.net."

```
  <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

    <style type="text/css">
                body{margin:19px 10px 20px 20px }
        .div1
        {
            background-color: lightGray;
            width:47%;
            height:1615px;
            float:left;
        }

        .div2
        {
            background-color: light gray;
            width:48%;
            height:1614px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
 .div3
        {
            background-color: black;
            width:2PX;
            height:1615px;
            float: left;

     }

        .container
        {
            width:100%;
            height: 1620px;
        }

        #TextArea1
    {
        height: 73px;
        margin-top: 0px;
            width: 244px;
        }
    #Submit1
    {
        width: 163px;
    }
        #Text6
        {
            width: 36px;
            margin-left: 9px;
        }
    .footer_leftNav{float: left;
            width: 1985px;
            height: 25px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
        #footer .footer_nav{font-size:11px;color:#a9b4c8;margin:13px auto 0px auto;width:860px;padding:0px 0 30px 0;text-align:left;border-top:solid 0px #546589;font-weight:100;}
.footer_nav_text{float:right;text-align:right;
            width: 304px;
            height: 18px;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        .listyle
    { 
        height: 17px;
        width: 494px;
    }
        #Text5
        {
            width: 142px;
        }
        .style3
        {
            font-size: x-large;
            color: #000000;
        }
        .style4
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #660033;
    }
    .style5
    {
        color: #660033;
    }
    .style6
    {
        color: #660033;
        font-family: "Bookman Old Style";
    }
    .style7
    {
        font-weight: 700;
        background-color: #FFCCCC;
    }
    .style8
    {
        color: #660033;
        background-color: #FFCCCC;
    }
    .style9
    {
        font-size: x-large;
    }
    #Text11
    {
        height: 25px;
        width: 155px;
        margin-top: 0px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
    .style11
    {
        font-size: small;
        color: #000000;
    }
    .style12
    {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #Submit2
    {
        height: 30px;
        width: 113px;
    }
        </style>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h1>strong><span class="style3">&nbsp;&
        </span><span class="style9">
        <span class="style4">&nbsp;PROCUREMENT REQUEST AND TRACKING&nbsp;</span></span><span class="style3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></strong></h1>
<h1><strong><span class="style3"> 


    <h1><strong><span class="style3"> 

        </span></strong>
    </h1>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="div1"><h1> 
            <span class="style6"><strong><span class="style7">MAKE A REQUEST !!</span></strong></span></h1>

<p>&nbsp;EMAIL&nbsp;ID*:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
            <    </p>
 zzz           
<p><span class="smallred">*</span>
EXTENSION:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" MaximumValue="4" MinimumValue="4" Type="Integer" Text="Invalid Extension Number" EnableClientScript="false" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator"></asp:RangeValidator>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; mobile NUMBER:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>

     </p>
<p><span class="smallred">*</span>
DEPARTMENT:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="Text4" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PROJECT
  <input type="radio" name="portal" id="radioprojectOff" onclick="inputname(this);"/> &nbsp; 
    *<input type="text" name="textprojectOff" id="TextProjectOff" value="Project Name" onclick="inputname(this);"/> 
    NON-PROJECT<input type="radio" name="portal"id="radiononprojectoff" /> &nbsp; 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function inputname(inField) {

        var fieldId = inField.id;
        var type = fieldId.substring(0, 4);

        if (type == 'text') {
            var name = fieldId.substring(4);
            var radioButton = document.getElementById("radio" + name);
            radioButton.checked = true;
        } else {
            var name;
            var textField;
            name = fieldId.substring(4);
            textField = document.getElementById("TextProjectOff");
//            textField = document.getElementById("text" + name);
            textField.focus();
        }
    }
</script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {

        if (document.getElementById("TextBox4").value == "") {
            alert("*mandatory fields");
            document.getElementById("TextBox4").focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("TextBox3").value == "") {
            alert("*mandatory fields");
            document.getElementById("TextBox3").focus();
            return false;
        }
         if (document.getElementById("Text4").value == "") {
            alert("*mandatory fields");
            document.getElementById("Text4").focus();
            return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("TextProjectOff").value == "") {
                alert("*mandatory fields");
                document.getElementById("textprojectoff").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("Text5").value == "") {
                alert("*mandatory fields");
                document.getElementById("Text5").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("Text6").value == "") {
                alert("*mandatory fields");
                document.getElementById("Text6").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("Text7").value == "") {
                alert("*mandaory fields");
                document.getElementById("Text7").focus();
                return false;
            }
        return true;
    }
</script>






&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<p>&nbsp;<p>*&nbsp;PRODUCT NAME:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="Text5" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="smallred">*</span>
QUANTITY&nbsp; : <input id="Text6" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; COST CENTER:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="Text9" type="text" /></p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>REQUIREMENT LEVEL:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>NORMAL</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>URGENT</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>WITHIN A MONTH</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <span class="smallred">*</span>
TARGET DATE FOR PROCUREMENT: <input id="Text7" type="text" /></p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
    <textarea id="TextArea1" name="S1"></textarea></p>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit1" OnClientClick=" return validate()" runat="server" 
            Text="Submit" Height="34px" Width="81px" />


            </p>

    </p>

div>
<div class="div3"> </div>

<div class="div2"><h1> 

      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

          function valid() {
              if (document.getElementById("Text10").value == "") {
                  alert("#mandatory fields");
                  document.getElementById("Text10").focus();
                  return false;
              }
              if (document.getElementById("Text11").value == "") {
                  alert("#mandatory fields");
                  document.getElementById("Text11").focus();
                  return false;
              }
              return true;
          }

        </script>  <span class="style8"><strong style="font-weight: 700">TRACK PRN!!</strong></span></h1>
            <p>

                #EMAIL ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="Text10" type="text" />
    </p>
<p>

        <strong><span class="style5">&nbsp;<span class="style9">#ENTER PRN:</span></span></strong></p>
    <p>

        <strong><span class="style5"><span class="style9">



            <input id="Text11" type="text" />


    <p class="style11">

        <span class="style12">&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter A Valid PRN 
        (Procurement Request Number)</span></p>
    <p class="style11">
        &nbsp;</p>
<p>



     <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick=" return valid()" runat="server" 
            Text="Submit" Height="34px" Width="81px" />
        </div>

    </div>
   </asp:Content>
```

I don't want to use such a lengthy coding and there are some runtime error which I am encountering during running the program..plz someone modify it and help me .

its my Internship project so try n help me as soon as possible.

Comment: hey @Shruti looking at your score i guess your are newbie to stackoverflow right! Please explain in a proper way so we can look into   your issue easliy..! using serverside validation or ClientSide(javascript)? For which field you need validation ?

Comment: atleast tell me for which control you need validation? Dont post whole page code..! just few lines of code where u stuck right now..?

Comment: yep..m new here as well as in asp.net..

Comment: i want validation over all my text boxes and range validation over some of them like extension ,mobile number..data type control over them...these problem can be solved by RangeValidator...my problem is that i want that when user click the submit button these validation should be checked...

Comment: yes i need server side validation

Comment: if (document.getElementById("TextBox4").value == "") {
            alert("*mandatory fields");
            document.getElementById("TextBox4").focus();
            return false;
right now m getting runtime error in here in the first line "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference 

"

Comment: offcourse you will get this error becoz when page is rendered the ID changes for eg when you are using masterpage TextBox1 is rendered as "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1". To know what is ID of your control for now you can view the page in Browser and rightclick on page->Click ViewSource here you will see what is the ID of the Control Rendered! please write in post and not in comment for code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **making field MANDATORY**:

Use `RequiredFieldValidator`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator  
         ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
         runat="server"  
         ControlToValidate="txtName"  
         ErrorMessage='Input Country!'  
         EnableClientScript="true"  
         SetFocusOnError="true"  
         Text="*"> 
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

For Validating Range of Number in `TextBox` use `RangeValidator`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" MaximumValue="200" MinimumValue="100" Type="Integer" ErrorMessage="Please input between 100 to 200.">  
</asp:RangeValidator>
```

**[Read more about Validations Here](http://shekharshetemcts.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/validations-using-net-javascript/)**

Hope this helps you!

Comment: -thnkeww sir....that was a great help...now m getting a new error in only those textboxes where I have given same max and min value(it is required) plz tell me how to solve it.. `EXTENSION* : <asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox> <asp:RangeValidator ID="rangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox1" Type="integer" MaximumValue="4" MinimumValue="4" ValidationGroup="valid" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="invalid extension" />`

Comment: if you want dont want range validator for TextBox and just you want to make it as required field then, remove the rangeValidator control and add required feild validator..